# How we can apply pandas groupby to get expected output?

Tags: python, pandas

```
Col1    Col2   Col3   Result

2        70     1      15
2        71     2      15
2        72     3      15
3        80     4      16    
3        81     5      16
3        82     6      16
3        2      15     16
3        3      16     16
```

I am new to pandas, can anyone explain how get last column result to add my existing data frame?

Comment: Could you describe how you want the new column to be calculated?

Comment: In Col1 value should be compare Col2 if matched then Col3 correspond value should get a result

Comment: Please, post the code of what you have tried, avoid asking low-effort question, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for all unique rows by `col2` values:

```
df['Res'] = df['Col1'].map(df.drop_duplicates('col2').set_index('Col2')['Col3'])
print (df)
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Result  Res
0     2    70     1      15   15
1     2    71     2      15   15
2     2    72     3      15   15
3     3    80     4      16   16
4     3    81     5      16   16
5     3    82     6      16   16
6     3     2    15      16   16
7     3     3    16      16   16
```

Comment: Hi when I'm running this code then getting error as : InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects, can you please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `merge`:

```
df.merge(df[['Col2','Col3']].rename(columns={'Col2':'Col1', 'Col3':'Res'}),
         on='Col1', how='left')
```

Output:

```
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Result  Res
0     2    70     1      15   15
1     2    71     2      15   15
2     2    72     3      15   15
3     3    80     4      16   16
4     3    81     5      16   16
5     3    82     6      16   16
6     3     2    15      16   16
7     3     3    16      16   16
```